# One shouldn't drink water in front of others - but other drinks are OK - why?

Tags: halacha, water, derech-eretz-manners, drinking

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 42:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.42.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> When you drink water, you should not drink in the presence of others,
> rather, turn your face away; **but when drinking other liquids, you need
> not turn your face away.**

Mishna Berura ([OC 170:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.2?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.170&lang2=bi)) writes similarly.

What is different with water that it improper to drink it in front of others - while other drinks are OK ?

Comment: [Pesachim 86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.86b.7) might be a relevant source. Rav Huna brei DRav Nosson drank a cup [of wine] in front of his hosts. They were surprised he didn't turn away from them when he drank, and he inferred from a Mishnah that it's unnecessary. Maybe the commentaries there might say something. If anything I see from there it's never necessary...

Answer (score 9):

Water is explicitly mentioned as problematic in the Talmud.

**Bechorot 44b**

> אמר רבי אבא בריה דרבי חייא בר אבא משתינין מים בפני רבים ואין שותין מים בפני רבים ותניא נמי הכי משתינין מים בפני רבים ואין שותין מים בפני רבים
>
> R. Abba b. R. Hiyya b. Abba reported in the name of R. Johanan: It is permitted to urinate in public, whereas it is not permitted to drink water in public. So indeed it has been taught: It is permitted to urinate in public, whereas it is not permitted to drink water in public.
>
> (Soncino translation)

Tosafot there suggests that water is unique in that it is drunken only by someone thirsty, whereas other things are normally consumed by people together:

> נראה דנקט מים לפי שאין רגילין לשתות כולן מים אלא הצמא בלבד אבל שאר דברים רגילין לשתות יחד

Comment: Do you understand the rationale for this?